# How can i prevent retrieve duplcated rows INNER JOIN query

Tags: sql, database

if i have two tables with inner join and i need to retrieve a specific data without duplicates row depend on "TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO" column

This is the used query and it doesn't accept distinct and when i try to use Group BY it force me to put all columns that mention after select statement

```
SELECT 
   TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_SUPER_USER, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_NAME ,  
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_ACCT_NO,  
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_NM , 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_CURR   , 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_CD  , 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_CD
FROM TABLE_B 
JOIN TABLE_A ON TABLE_A.LINK_USER_ID = TABLE_B.E_DEN_SUPER_USER
WHERE TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_STATUS ='00' 
  AND E_DEN_SUPER_USER > 1000 
  AND E_DEN_STATUS = 'A' 
  AND E_DEN_Test_CD IS NOT NULL 
  AND E_DEN_Test_NM IS NOT NULL 
  AND E_DEN_NAME IS NOT NULL 
  AND E_DEN_ACCT_NO IS NOT NULL
  AND TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO LIKE '_____________' 
Group by 
   TABLE_A.LINK_USER_ID;
```

I'm try to retrieve data without duplicated row depend on "TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO" column

Comment: "it doesn't accept distinct".  Can you share with us why that is not accepted?

Comment: Also can you tag the database you are using ?

Comment: -Oracle databases SQL+

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve data without duplicate rows based on the "TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO" column, you can use the DISTINCT keyword in your query. However, you mentioned that it doesn't accept DISTINCT. In that case, you can use a subquery to achieve the desired result. Here's an example of how you can modify your query:

```
SELECT 
   subquery.LINK_ACCT_NO, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_SUPER_USER, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_NAME,  
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_ACCT_NO,  
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_NM, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_CURR, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_CD, 
   TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_CD
FROM TABLE_B 
JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT LINK_ACCT_NO, LINK_USER_ID
   FROM TABLE_A
   WHERE LINK_ACCT_STATUS = '00' 
     AND LINK_ACCT_NO LIKE '_____________'
) subquery ON subquery.LINK_USER_ID = TABLE_B.E_DEN_SUPER_USER
WHERE TABLE_B.E_DEN_SUPER_USER > 1000 
  AND TABLE_B.E_DEN_STATUS = 'A' 
  AND TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_CD IS NOT NULL 
  AND TABLE_B.E_DEN_Test_NM IS NOT NULL 
  AND TABLE_B.E_DEN_NAME IS NOT NULL 
  AND TABLE_B.E_DEN_ACCT_NO IS NOT NULL;
```

In this modified query, the subquery retrieves the distinct values of "LINK_ACCT_NO" along with their corresponding "LINK_USER_ID" from "TABLE_A". Then, the main query joins the subquery with "TABLE_B" based on the "LINK_USER_ID" column. This should give you the desired result with distinct rows based on "TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO".

Answer (score -1):

You should never use group by to make the rows distinct. Its my personal practice. It can become a nasty habit that can trick you.

There is no reason why distinct should not work in this case.

I guess you have two or more different values of LINK_ACCT_NO inside TABLE A for the same E_DEN_SUPER_USER in the table B. Group by or distinct wont help you in this case if the columns in select statement stays the same.

Take in example table City(CityID, CityName) and Person(PersonID, PersonName, BirthCityID).

If you make the join between them on the BirthCityID column and make a query like this

SELECT City.CityName,
Person.PersonName
FROM City
INNER JOIN Person ON City.ID = Person.BirthCityID

1. Moscow Steve
2. Moscow Peter
   3........

You will as many rows as there is Persons for the each City in the City table.

Your only solution is to use distinct (without group by) and remove the TABLE_A.LINK_ACCT_NO column from the select statement. Either that either check your table design and analyze how did two different values occur for the same user.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your first answer and sharing your experience. I have three suggestions how to improve your answer. Please, consider them. 1. The beginning is not the answer, and not the correct advice. You know, it depends, so not "never" ;-) 2. You negate the conditions - the author said "no DISTINCT". You can ask in comments for a reason, if you want, but do not put it into the answer - then it becomes "an opinion only". 3. Short your answer to the REAL answer, so an alternative. This is not a discussion, the answer have to be clear. And... keep going! :-)

Comment: Hi Gerard, I wanted to add a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow it :( I will give my best, thanks!!!

Comment: Everyone on this forum started without this permission - so don't give up! :-)